# gridview sorting

Tags: asp.net

I have a `gridview` that I load from a `linq` query.

`MyGridData` is a the list that's returned from the `linq` query and that contains a variable called `MyVariable`. So, in the code behind  I have:

```
MyGrid.DataSource = MyGridData;
MyGrid.DataBind();
```

I then went to the `aspx` source and added `AllowSorting = true` and to the boundfield I want to enable sorting for, I added `SortExpression = "MyVariable"`.

When the page renders, if I click on the header of the column to sort the grid, I get a yellow death screen with this message:

```
The GridView 'MyGrid' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the handler for the [Sorting-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx) in the Codebehind. Sort your datasource and bind your grid again.